Using Node with firebase-admin authentication, does the jwt signing/verification function run locally or is it processed on Google's servers?
Basically, I'm looking into offloading the synchronous(Node event loop-blocking, cpu intensive) JWT verification/signing methods with firebase-admin authentication, and couldn't find a clear answer in the provided firebase sdk code or the documentation on whether or not Firebase runs these methods locally on the server that calls the method, or if Firebase is handling these on their own servers and sending back the result.
To put it another way, whom takes the CPU time burden of handling the JWT? One's Node server calling eg. verifyIdToken(), etc... or Google's auth servers?
I've exhaustively researched the documentation and Node firebase-admin SDK code and couldn't find a clear-cut answer on this.
